# How is Aut(G) = Aut(G¯)? (where G¯ is the complement of G)

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group, graph-isomorphism

For a Graph G, I am trying to understand how the automorphism of G is equivalent to the automorphism of the complement of G.

I understand that an automorphism is an isomorphism of G onto itself. This, in fact, seems like it should be a fairly basic concept and so my confusion is likely in relation to what abstract concept an automorphism actually manifests as, and therefore how the equivalency can be seen.

Comment: What is the complement of a group? Do you mean the [opposite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_group)?

Comment: @Thorgott I think $G$ is a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because
$$(f(i),f(j))\in E(G) \iff (i,j)\in E(G)$$
is equivalent to
$$(f(i),f(j))\not\in E(G) \iff (i,j)\not\in E(G),$$
which is equivalent to
$$(f(i),f(j))\in E(\overline{G}) \iff (i,j)\in E(\overline{G}).$$

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I am still having trouble imagining a visual example of this using graphs, if you have any good ideas where I could look for such?

Comment: Another helpful thought for me is that automorphisms preserve adjacencies and hence non-adjacencies. That's an easy way to think about this concept.